# Possible to add KEEPFIXED PLAN option to reduce the recompile in SQL Server 2005 in Production Env?

Tags: sql-server-2005, performance, stored-procedures, best-practices

I'm not sure if it is good to enable the **KEEPFIXED PLAN** to reduce the impact of recompilation in the **Production Env**?

I'd know if we may gain performance after that or on the other hand it will be even worse.

For my case, I have a batch of stored procedures running in SQL Server 2005 and some one of need to run in a fixed loop condition.

Thanks!

Vance

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I wouldn't use it.

There are better ways on managing this with [asynchronous statistics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190397.aspx) or plan guides nowadays. I've only ever seen this hint used on some old trading database that was geared towards Sybase/very old SQL Server.

Also, you now have [statement level recompilation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966425.aspx) that may fit your use case better

But really, you'll have to try it and find out in your situation...

Comment: Just an observation: sp_whoisactive (11.32) uses it